# VideoStream external URL mp4 file in PHP

Tags: php, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

Please help me with this VideoStream because its not working.

I have video link
http://91.121.207.115/downloads/American.Traitor.The.Trial.of.Axis.Sally.007.BR.mp4

But its not playing in normal html5 video

Then I came up here and its working fine.
https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

I already tried as I can but still not working.

index.php

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="stream.php" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

stream.php

```
include "VideoStream.php";
$stream = new VideoStream("http://91.121.207.115/downloads/American.Traitor.The.Trial.of.Axis.Sally.007.BR.mp4");
$stream->start();exit;
```

[VideoStream.php](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ranacseruet/9826293/raw/7f8100a36cd1044aab4d046873be1eed1e1dba40/VideoStream.php) file

Please help me to work that video stream in html5 video. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use PHP to provide video file bytes into HTML5 `<video>` then try as:

(1) index.php: (can be `index.html`)...

```
<video width="640" height="400" controls>
<source src="stream.php" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

(2) stream.php:

```
<?php
    
    $file = "http://91.121.207.115/downloads/American.Traitor.The.Trial.of.Axis.Sally.007.BR.mp4";
    
    $contents = readfile( $file );
    echo $contents; //# send back to HTML...
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much. .works like a charm :)
but can't seek, forward or backward.